# C - reading multiple integers and floats with sscanf

Tags: c, file, integer, fgets, scanf

I am doing a practice problem for my C programming class which tells me to write a program that reads in variables from a file. On the first line, it is supposed to read in an integer N.

From there, it should read an integer, and then five floating points on every line for N lines. It is supposed to calculate a sum of all the floats in the file and write it to another file.

I have written a program that should do this using fgets to copy a line to a string, and sscanf to dissect it and assign the segments to different array locations. However, I am encountering some issue with obtaining extraneous information through sscanf (perhaps a null value or the newline). It is not storing the integer N properly (it is producing large random values and creating a runtime error by infinite loop), and it probably isn't working inside of the loop either.

How can I perfect this so that it reads in the integers and floats properly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_STRING 30
#define MAX_LINE_SIZE 200

int main(void)
{
    FILE *f1, *f2;
    char filename[MAX_STRING];
    char fileline[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
    int N, eN;
    float totalwage = 0;
    int* ssn;
    float** wage;

    printf ("Enter a file name for data analysis: ");
    scanf ("%s", &filename); //get file name from user input for reading

    f1 = fopen (filename, "r");

    fgets (fileline, MAX_LINE_SIZE, f1); //read first line
    sscanf (fileline, "%d", &N); //pull integer from first line to determine how many lines follow

    for (eN = 0; eN < N; eN ++) //read N lines following the first
    {
        // VVV read single line from file
        fgets (fileline, MAX_LINE_SIZE, f1);
        // VVV record data from line
        sscanf (fileline, "%d, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f", &ssn[eN], &wage[eN][0], &wage[eN][1], &wage[eN][2], &wage[eN][3], &wage[eN][4]);
        // VVV add the 5 wages on each line to a total
        totalwage += wage[eN][0] + wage[eN][1] + wage[eN][2] + wage[eN][3] + wage[eN][4];
    }

    fclose (f1);

    printf ("Enter a file name for the result: ");
    scanf ("%s", &filename); //get file name from user input for writing

    f2 = fopen (filename, "w");

    fprintf (f2, "%f", totalwage); //store total of wages in file specified by user

    printf ("\nThe information has been stored. Press any key to exit.\n");
    getchar();
}
```

The file being read is 'wages.txt' and it's contents are as follows:

```
10
1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50
2, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
3, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29
4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
5, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150
6, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41
7, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80
8, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25
9, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120
10, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 2000
```

As a recap, the issue is that there is a runtime error in which the program crashes due to some sort of infinite loop. Through some debugging I saw that it was not reading in the first line as an integer properly. Instead of the value ten, it was storing large values as though it read a null character.

---

I have added code in attempt to allocate memory for ssn and wages. However, I am not sure if it was done correctly, and the program still has a crashing runtime error.

```
ssn = malloc (N*MAX_STRING);
wage = malloc (N*MAX_STRING);
for (eN = 0; eN < N; eN ++)
{
    wage[eN] = malloc (N*MAX_STRING);
}
```

Comment: "C - reading multiple integers and floats with sscanf" - no, using `fgets()` and `strtol()` and `strtod()`. Furthermore, `scanf ("%s", &filename);` is a type mismatch-based UB. The long `sscanf()` line involving the `wage` pointer is also UB, because that pointer doesn't point anywhere, it is uninitialized.

Comment: Not one return-value check from *any* of those library calls. And you wonder what may be going wrong?

Comment: I have successfully allocated memory for ssn and wage. I am still getting unpredictable values from sscanf.

Comment: If you're not doing anything except summing the wages, then you don't need an array big enough to hold all the wages.  You might need an array big enough to hold one line's worth of wages (so a single call to `sscanf()` reads the data into the array, and then you sum the array into the total.  You could even write the code so you only need a single `float` variable to read values into, plus the one to hold the sum of the wages, though that's a bit harder and probably not worth the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by others

```
scanf ("%s", &filename);
```

should be:

```
scanf ("%s", filename);
```

Note that `sscanf` is a big problem if the number of columns change

Revised for use with `strtod`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_STRING 30
#define MAX_LINE_SIZE 200
#define COLS 5

int main(void)
{
    FILE *f1, *f2;
    char filename[MAX_STRING];
    char fileline[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
    int N, eN, i;
    float totalwage = 0;
    float (*wage)[COLS];
    char *p;

    printf ("Enter a file name for data analysis: ");
    scanf ("%s", filename); //get file name from user input for reading
    f1 = fopen (filename, "r");
    fgets (fileline, MAX_LINE_SIZE, f1); //read first line
    sscanf (fileline, "%d", &N); //pull integer from first line to determine how many lines follow
    wage = malloc((sizeof(float) * COLS) * N);
    /* check malloc ... */
    for (eN = 0; eN < N; eN ++) //read N lines following the first
    {
        // VVV read single line from file
        p = fgets (fileline, MAX_LINE_SIZE, f1);
        strtol(p, &p, 10); /* skip first column */
        for (i = 0; i < COLS; i++) {
            wage[eN][i] = strtod(p + 1, &p); /* p+1 skip comma, read a float */
            totalwage += wage[eN][i]; /* sum */
        }
    }
    free(wage);
    fclose (f1);
    printf ("Enter a file name for the result: ");
    scanf ("%s", filename); //get file name from user input for writing
    f2 = fopen (filename, "w");
    fprintf (f2, "%f", totalwage); //store total of wages in file specified by user
    printf ("\nThe information has been stored. Press any key to exit.\n");
    getchar();
    fclose(f2); /* you forget to close f2 */
    return 0;
}
```

Also note that you are reading floats only for sum, there is no need to store them, so `malloc` can be avoided, and in the real world check the result of `fopen`, `fgets` ...

Comment: This works seamlessly, and it is understandable. Thank you! I am reading through it so I can learn the concepts. Two things are confusing me though. First being that the sscanf for N and related lines were not altered but in mine it was not reading that properly. Do you know why?

The other is I am unsure of what the base 10 is in strtol.

Comment: The problem in you sscanf? scan of N was correct, in the scan of lines you are trying to store the values in a non allocated block (solved using malloc). Base 10 means that you are reading in decimal notation (could be 8 for octal and 16 for hexadecimal)

Comment: Another thing: you don't need to store the number of lines in the file to determine how many lines follows, read the documentation of [fgets](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/fgets.html). If the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream shall be set and fgets() shall return a null pointer.

Comment: A lot of these things that I didn't need to do were part of the practice problem, in which I was supposed to store the data, and also read in the number of lines. It's all working now. I allocated memory for wages and ssn successfully, and switched to strtol() and strtod() functions like you said.

Is char *p storing the location in the file that it stopped at in the second argument?

Comment: No, `p` points to the begin of fileline (and on each iterarion, `strtod` change this position to the next comma in the string)

Answer (score 3):

You're not allocating any memory for wage.  It's declared as a pointer to a pointer to a float; that's fine, but the pointers don't point anywhere.

Same thing for ssn.

After this line:

```
sscanf (fileline, "%d", &N); //pull integer from first line to determine how many lines follow
```

You need to allocate memory for ssn and wage.

Since this is homework, I'm not going to tell you how to allocate the memory; you need to be able to figure that out yourself.

Comment: `scanf ("%s", &filename);` is UB too.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll continue research. Also, it's not homework, its practice problems for test prep.

Comment: Allocate memory like this?

   ssn = malloc (N*MAX_STRING);
   wage = malloc (N*MAX_STRING);
   for (eN = 0; eN < N; eN ++)
   {
       wage[eN] = malloc (N*MAX_STRING);
   }

Comment: @River - ssn needs to be an array of N integers; wage needs to be an array of N (array of 5 floats).  Your code is close, but not quite.

Comment: Like this?     ssn = malloc (N);
    wage = malloc (N);
    for (eN = 0; eN < N; eN ++)
    {
        wage[eN] = malloc (5);
    }

Comment: malloc takes a quantity of bytes.  sizeof() is your friend here.

Answer (score 0):

when you allocate memory to store one float you need to understand that a float value consists of four bytes so when you call malloc it needs to take this into account, to store one float : `malloc( sizeof(float ) )` to store an array size N of float `malloc( N*sizeof(float ) )` for int it is `sizeof(int)`